# Импорт библиотеки C++ на C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Пытаюсь через [Dllimport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) добавить в проект на C# библиотеку написанную на C++
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Не могу объявить эту функцию

```
short L862_GetResponse ( short hPort, short *Len, char * pData, long Timeout );
```

основная проблема с `short *Len, char * pData`

Comment: Конечно, будет проблема. Откуда C# знает (да и мы откуда знаем), как маршалировать указатель? Это на самом деле массив? Или это out-переменная? Или ещё что-то?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант

```
[DllImport("*.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
static extern short L862_GetResponse ( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]short hPort, IntPtr Len, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string pData, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]long Timeout );
```

Это из предположения, что `sizeof(short) = 2, sizeof(long) = 8`

И не забудьте в нативной библиотеке вашу функцию обернуть в `extern "C"`, чтобы названия функции при экспорте функций из dll сохранились.

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе много неизвестных? Приблизительно так должно выглядеть!

```
[DllImport(@"C:\", ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "L862_GetResponse")]
public static extern short L862_GetResponse(short hPort,  ref short Len, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]byte[] pData, long Timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположу по именам аргументов, что вариант на C# будет таким

```
short L862_GetResponse(short port, out int length, byte[] data, int timeout)
```

Comment: Не-не-не, не так просто. Нужно как минимум (1) проставить атрибуты типа `MarshalAs`, (2) выяснить _точную_ длину `short` и `long` в нативном коде (она, в отличие от C#, не фиксирована!), (3) вроде бы нужно убрать C++-специфическую декорацию имени при помощи `extern "C"`.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Поэтому это и было предположение.

Comment: а int разве short?

Comment: В C/C++ длина типа `int` не фиксирована, как и `short`. В С# размер `int`  4 байта, `short` -  2